# How do I add a video thumbnail to product detail page in BigCommerce?

Tags: video, bigcommerce

How do I add a video thumbnail to product detail page below the product image in BigCommerce?

Comment: What page are you trying to get a video thumbnail on? The way this might be accomplished can vary between a product page, category page, etc.